# drupal - collection field with status - publish checkbox

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fields, drupal-field-collection

is there a way to have a publish checkbox on a collection field associated to a content type ?

if i have 3 items on a collection field associated to a node , one i want to set it unpublished so only 2 are displayed.

```
cars content type:
 -mercedes....
 -bmw.....
 -audi.... = unpublished
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default (through the UI) you can't do it.

You can do it programmatically by adding a check-box on your collection by using _form_alter() and add your own validation callback where you'll can modify referenced node accordingly.

Comment: can Rules validate this insted of a validation callback?